# Please explain couple of proguard keywords

Tags: android, proguard

Would any of you be so kind as to rephrase (in your own words) the explanations for some of the proguard keywords that are written in their manual? I have hard time understanding in full what some of them mean, and what changes if they are not there in the .cfg file.

The keywords I'm interested are:
1) -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses and -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

The second is being explained as:

*Specifies not to ignore package visible library class members (fields and methods). By default, ProGuard skips these class members while parsing library classes, as program classes will generally not refer to them. Sometimes however, program classes reside in the same packages as library classes, and they do refer to their package visible class members. In those cases, it can be useful to actually read the class members, in order to make sure the processed code remains consistent.*

First of all, does it refere only in the context of external jars? Second, what is the difference between those flags reside in the .cfg file vs not being there?

2) -libraryjars, I'm lost for that one. What is the purpose of this keyword? On proguard manual page it reads:

*Specifies the library jars (or aars, wars, ears, zips, apks, or directories) of the application to be processed.*

So does it mean, that if I don't use this flag, then those jars are not put under the whole obfuscation process? But if that's the case, then why when I don't use this keyword, there are a lot of warnings for classes in those jars in the proguard output?

Next it says:

*The files in these jars will not be included in the output jars.*

What does it mean exactly? It means, that if this flag is set, then all other files aside .class files will not be included in the parent's application jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of reading I think I got my answers. Especialy what helped me was reading many of the creator of ProGuard answers here at StackOverflow.

Let me start with the jars topic. Libraryjars is usually the platfrom jar, the application is build against, so android.jar is a good example here. This jar will not be processed, it's classes will not reside in the output apk, because they will be all on the clients device. They will not be obfuscated or shrunk, because a) even if they were they would not be coppied into the output apk anyway, and b) if they were obfuscated then it would crash application due to the fact that say Activity during obfuscation would have the name changed to "a", but on the clients device the android API is not changed.

So libraryjars is used for all the jars that proguard needs when processing our app, but which jars will not be included (or it's class files) in the final apk.

Injars on the other hand are all the jars that we want to be shrunk/obfuscated etc (unless we use keep* keywords).

Now the reason that I had so much difficulty was because there were conflicting information about those keywords all over the place. Some people said to use -injars, some said to use -libraryjars, some said neighter. What I found out later on, is that the last answer is correct. No -libraryjars or -injars keyword is needed because ADT does all this for the developer, and it uses the -injars keyword with all the jars residing in the /libs folder.

That is also the reason why I found many people using the "keep" keywords with the packages of one of the jars to ignore it's obfuscation/shrinking. The reason for it is that because ADT uses -injars keyword for those jars by default (and not libraryjars which would essentialy do the same in this context) then those jars are marked to be processed (obfuscated/shrunk). To negate this effect, people use -keep keywords for the packages of those jars.

As for the #1 question:

*First of all, does it refere only in the context of external jars?* The answer is no. It reffers to all the libraries even referenced inside the attached jars

*Second, what is the difference between those flags reside in the .cfg file vs not being there?* From what I found out it's for helping the ProGuard with processing of those libraries.